# How do I find a text string in word and change it with Field codes

Tags: microsoft-word

I have huge documents, say agreement where currently my company name is written as Text. As we have different company name and want to use the same agreement as template, like to find all the company name in the base document and replace it with Field - Company.
How can i achieve it.

Comment: can you make a very small document like one page, with an example of 3 text strings and fields, then link to it

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a field in the document
2. Select the field and copy to the clipboard
3. In the "Search and Replace" dialog,

   - find: *your text string*
   - replace with: `^c`. This special code means to replace with the content of the clipboard.